# passing a portion of an array of a derived type that contains an allocatable component

Tags: oop, memory-leaks, fortran, gfortran, derived-types

I'm having trouble when I pass a portion of an array of a derived type which has an allocatable component. A (probable) memory leaks seems to occur (unfortunatly valgrind is not yet available on mac 10.14/mojave, so I simply used a long do loop and looked the memory used with top).

Consider the following test program which reproduces my problem in a simpler context:

```
program test_leak
  implicit none

  type :: vint_t
     integer, allocatable :: col(:)
  end type vint_t

  type(vint_t) :: row(4)
  integer      :: i, Ind(2)=[2,3]

  do i = 1, 4
     allocate(row(i)%col(i))
  end do

  row(1)%col(1) = 11  
  row(2)%col(1) = 21 ; row(2)%col(2) = 22
  row(3)%col(1) = 31 ; row(3)%col(2) = 32 ; row(3)%col(3) = 33
  row(4)%col(1) = 41 ; row(4)%col(2) = 42 ; row(4)%col(3) = 43 ; row(4)%col(4) = 44

  do i = 1, 1000000
     call do_nothing ( row(Ind) ) ! (version #A) with this version and with gfortran: memory grows with iter
     !call do_nothing ( row(2:3) ) ! (version #B) but not with this version

     if (mod(i,10000) == 0) then
        print*,i ; read*
     end if
  end do

contains

  subroutine do_nothing ( a )
    type(vint_t), intent(in) :: a(:)
  end subroutine do_nothing

end program test_leak
```

- The problem occurs with gfortran (8.2) and not with ifort (19) nor with nagfor (6.2) (with nagfor and ifort the used memory is stable during the iterations and ca 400 Kb, while it reaches ca 30 Mb with gfortran!).
- A final procedure doesn't solve the problem.
- The problem disapears if the allocatable member "col" is replaced by an explicit array (say col(4)) or if the version #B is used.
- The problem also occurs with an allocatable character component.
- If I print "a" in the subroutine "do_nothing" both versions give the correct result.

Does anyone have some insight on this issue? Of course I can design the called subroutines by passing the array Ind (do_nothing(row, Ind)) but that would be somewhat a pity.

Comment: That's likely undesired behaviour, but you are aware that `row([2,3])` and `row(2:3)` are very different things?  Could you, then try `row(ind(1):ind(2))` if you are more after the second form?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with gfortran 8.2.1 or 9.0 on x86_64-*-freebsd.  Perhaps, an issue with Apple's memory management.

Comment: @francescalus: Yes, and I put the version #B only to try to understand the origin of the problem. 
Indeed, putting row(ind(1):ind(2)) works, but that's not what I want to do: the values of the ind array must be arbitrary and not necessarily ordered (for example, in the test program, it could be something like ind =[3,2] or[1,4,2],....).

Comment: @steve: Interesting. I will try it on another OS.

Comment: Forgot to mention that valgrind on FreeBSD shows no leaks.

Comment: With gfortran 8.2.0 + OSX10.11 (El Capitan), the memory grows linearly with iterations, either with or without optimization. -fcheck-array-temporaries gives no message. And valgrind reports a leak of 20,000,000 bytes. So, the behavior on my computer seems the same as the question...

Comment: As a workaround, I tried "type(vint_t), allocatable :: row_part(:)" and then "row_part = col( Ind ) ; call do_nothing( row_part )" in the do-loop. Then, the memory issue goes away on my computer. (But for performance, simply passing Ind separately might be much faster?)

Comment: ["with nagfor and ifort the used memory is ... ca 400 Mb" may be a typo of 400 Kb?]

Comment: @roygvib: oh yes, sorry: 400 Kb with nagfor and ifort. I corrected it.

Comment: @roygvib: "As a workaround, I tried "type(vint_t), allocatable :: row_part(:)" and then "row_part = col( Ind ) ". I had also tried this workaround with the same observation as yours and I agree with you: passing the indexes as argument of the subroutine is certainly wiser.

Comment: On fortran 8.2.0 + osx10.13.6 I couldn't reproduce your problem. And yes, I think you should report the problem

Comment: @francescalus: sorry, I didn't quite understand your suggestion. I therefore confirm that when putting row(ind(1):ind(2)) the issue goes away and the program requires the same memory as with row(2:3). Thank you all. Do you think it is useful to report the problem on bugzilla?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues: That's amazing. I tried on an old mac (10.9/maverick) and gfortran 6.3 with the same issue.